# Issues with ncat options -g -G -s --sctp

Tags: linux, networking, netcat

I am new to `ncat` and am having issues with few options: `-g -G -s --sctp`

#### `-g` option

```
ncat -g proxy-source-IP -v remote-IP 31337
```

From the `source-IP` to `remote-IP` it returns `source-IP`, and *not* `proxy-source-IP` as it is supposed to.

For example, running the command from a machine with an IP of 1.0.0.0

```
ncat -g 1.0.1.0 -v 1.1.0.0 31337
```

is supposed to return 1.0.1.0, *not* 1.0.0.0

#### `-G` option

```
ncat -G 4 -v remote-IP 31337
```

what exactly does `-G 4` mean here?

#### `-s` option

```
ncat -s proxy-source-IP -v remote-IP 31337  #
```

from `source-IP` to `remote-IP` returns the `source-IP`, *not* the `proxy-source-IP` as it is supposed to. For example, from a machine with an IP of 1.0.0.0:

```
ncat -s 1.0.1.0 -v 1.1.0.0 31337
```

is supposed to return 1.0.1.0, *not* 1.0.0.0

#### `--sctp` option

```
ncat -v remote-IP --sctp 31338
```

The input goes to the shell, *not* `ncat` as `STDERR` replies input (see below)

```
Ncat: Version 6.00 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
foo
No command 'foo' found, did you mean:
Command 'fio' from package 'fio' (main)
Command 'xoo' from package 'xoo' (main)
Command 'fop' from package 'fop' (main)
Command 'fox' from package 'objcryst-fox' (main)
Command 'zoo' from package 'zoo' (main)
Command 'goo' from package 'goo' (main)
foo: command not found
```

Can anyone explain these odd behaviors?